# Outlook Web Add-ins embed document and update properties

Tags: office-js, outlook-addin, office-addins, outlook-web-addins, outlook-restapi

I have created an add-in in word to retrieve data from base64(.docx) and inserted the data.

```
const body = context.document.body;
body.insertFileFromBase64(templateBase64, Word.InsertLocation.replace);
```

Also, added the properties using

```
customProperties.forEach(c => {
  if (c.key)
    context.document.properties.customProperties.add(c.key, c.value || ' ');
});
```

May I know how to do the same for outlook? I don't want to attach the document to outlook, I want to insert the document text into body and update the properties.

Thanks

Comment: Could you expand more on the scenario, do you want to take content from a word docx file and insert into a Outlook message body?  Or do you have HTML/text body you want to add to Outlook's compose? Are we talking about an addin that runs in message compose scenario in Outlook?

Comment: I want to take content from word docx file and insert into outlook message body. Yes, this is for message compose scenario.

Comment: Outlook has apis to modify the body, but it only accepts HTML and Text. Any data that can be converted to HTML/Text can be inserted...but anything else cannot via those apis.

Answer (score 0):

Currently the feature: API to load and insert content from word file into message compose, you requested, is not a part of the product. We track Outlook add-in feature requests on our user-voice page. Please add your request there. Feature requests on user-voice are considered, when we go through our planning process.

https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-general/category/131778-outlook-add-ins

Comment: Please refrain from signing your posts.